# Storing Scraped data in csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I am learning web scraping using scrapy. Having Pretty Fun with it. The only problem is I can't save the scraped data in the way I want to.

The below code scrapes reviews from Amazon. How to make the storing of data better?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
import csv

class Oneplus6Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'oneplus6'
    allowed_domains = ['amazon.in']
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Silk-White-128GB- 
    Storage/product-reviews/B078BNQ2ZS/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewopt_sr? 
    ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&filterByStar=positive&pageNumber=1']

    def parse(self, response):

        writer = csv.writer(open('jack.csv','w+'))

        opinions = response.xpath('//*[@class="a-size-base a-link-normal 
        review-title a-color-base a-text-bold"]/text()').extract()

        for opinion in opinions:
            yield({'Opinion':opinion})

        reviewers = response.xpath('//*[@class="a-size-base a-link-normal 
        author"]/text()').extract()

        for reviewer in reviewers:
            yield({'Reviewer':reviewer})
            

         verified = response.xpath('//*[@class="a-size-mini a-color-state a- 
         text-bold"]/text()').extract()

         for verified_buyer in verified:
             yield({'Verified_buyer':verified_buyer})
        
          ratings = response.xpath('//span[@class="a-icon- 
          alt"]/text()').extract()

          for rating in ratings:
              yield({'Rating':rating[0]})


           model_bought = response.xpath('//a[@class="a-size-mini a-link- 
           normal a-color-secondary"]/text()').extract()

          for model in model_bought:
              yield({'Model':model})
```

I tried using scrapy's default way **-o** method and also tried using csv.

The data gets stored in single row.I am very new to pandas and csv modules and I can't figure out how to store the scraped data in a proper format?

***It is storing all the values in one single row.***

I want the different values in different rows

**Eg: Reviews|Rating|Model|**

but I just can't figure out how to do it

How can I do it ?

Comment: It is difficult to say which way is the best. In general I would use .json files and the json module in Python to store data. You can also read these files with pandas.

Comment: Give us a basic view or an example to show how the data is stored.

Answer (score 1):

It's observed in your code that you're trying to extract records with different types: they're all `dict` objects with a single key, where the key might have different values ("Opinion", "Reviewer", etc.).

In Scrapy, exporting data to CSV is handled by [`CsvItemExporter`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/dc95ecb/scrapy/exporters.py#L206) where [the `_write_headers_and_set_fields_to_export` method](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/dc95ecb/scrapy/exporters.py#L253) is what matters with your current problem, as the exporter needs to know the list of fields (column names) before writing the first item.

Specifically:

1. It'll first check the `fields_to_export` attribute (configured by the `FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS` setting via feed exporter ([related code here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/dc95ecb/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py#L196)))
2. If unset:

   - 2.a. If the first item is a `dict`, it'll use all its keys as the column name.
   - 2.b. If the first item is a `scrapy.Item`, it'll use the keys from the item definition.

Thus there're several ways to resolve the problem:

1. You may define a `scrapy.Item` class with all possible keys you need, and yield items of this type in your code (just fill in the one field you need, and leave others empty, for any specific record).
2. Or, properly configure the `FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS` setting and leave other part of your existing code unchanged.

I suppose the hints above are sufficient. Please let me know if you need further examples.

Answer (score 0):

To set csv data format one of the easiest way is to clean data using excel power queries, follow these steps:

1. Open csv file in excel.
2. Select all values using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
3. Then click on table from insert and create table.
4. After create table click on **Data** from top menu and select
   **From Table**.
5. Know they open new excel window **power queries**.
6. Select any column and click on **split column**.
7. From **split column** select **by delimiter**.
8. Know select **delimiter** like **comma, space** etc.
9. Final step: Select **advanced option** in which there are two
   options split in rows or column.

You can do all type of data cleaning using these power queries, this is the easiest way to setup data format according to your need.